# I have a unity Asset that worked fine in unity 2020 but updating in 2022 throws error

Tags: unity-game-engine

So thankfully I have the source code for it, here is the error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an objectSIDGIN.Common.Editors.AsyncForcePump.ExecuteContinuations () (at <5e8412271d9b40fb9a7c081e4f92d612>:0)UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at <8e887700cd7e4674989da7b046e8eaa6>:0)
```

and here is the in AsyncForcePump:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEditor;
namespace SIDGIN.Patcher.Unity
{
    public static class AsyncForcePump
    {
        [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
        static void Initialize() => EditorApplication.update += ExecuteContinuations;

        static MethodInfo execMethod;
        static void ExecuteContinuations()
        {
            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            if (execMethod == null)
                execMethod = context.GetType().GetMethod("Exec", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            execMethod.Invoke(context, null);
        }
    }
```

Sadly, even if I comment out everything and rebuild, the error is there, I don't know where to start with this issue.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)